# How do I combine two objects by merging the values of same properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

Is there a way we can combine two objects by nesting the values if properties are same instead of overwriting ?
Eg:

```
const obj1 = {a:10,b:13}
const obj2 = {a:84,c:70}

desired result : 
combinedObject = {a:{0:10,1:84}, b:13, c:70}
```

Comment: Why not `a: [10,84]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const obj1 = { a: 10, b: 13 }
const obj2 = { a: 84, c: 70, d: 40 }

function foo(obj1, obj2) {

    const newObject = {}
    for (const key in { ...obj1, ...obj2 }) {
        const element1 = obj1[key];
        const element2 = obj2[key];
        if (element1 && element2)
            newObject[key] = [element1, element2]
        else if (element1)
            newObject[key] = element1
        else if (element2)
            newObject[key] = element2
    }
    return newObject
}
console.log(foo(obj1, obj2))
```

Answer (score 0):

you must follow the rules of object definitions

```js
const obj1 = {a:10,b:13}
const obj2 = {a:84,c:70}
//it can be like this
combinedObject = {a:[10,84], b:13, c:70}
// you can access to that value like this 
let value = combinedObject.a[0];
```

and finally, you can use this code for the combination

```js
    const obj1 = { a: 10, b: 13 };
    const obj2 = { a: 84, c: 70 };
    const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2);
    let combinedObject = { ...obj1 };
    for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      if (combinedObject[props[i]])
        combinedObject[props[i]] = [combinedObject[props[i]], obj2[props[i]]];
      else combinedObject[props[i]] = obj2[props[i]];
    }
    //result :{a:[10,84], b:13, c:70}
```

as you wish

```js
const obj1 = { a: 10, b: 13 };
    const obj2 = { a: 84, c: 70 };
    const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2);
    let combinedObject = { ...obj1 };
    for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      if (combinedObject[props[i]])
        combinedObject[props[i]] = {0:combinedObject[props[i]], 1:obj2[props[i]]};
      else combinedObject[props[i]] = obj2[props[i]];
    }
    console.log(combinedObject);
//result :{a:{0:10,1:84}, b:13, c:70}
```

Comment: It does not work if a property is an object in one object or the other as well

Comment: it's working and it is the result ={a:[10,84], b:13, c:70}

Comment: can you test it with the following data please, also this is not the result asked by the author, you provide another solution which is fine but do not answer the original question.
--- here are the data ---
const obj1 = { a: { 0: 10, 1: 11 }, b: 13 }
const obj2 = { a: 84, c: 70, d: 40 }

Comment: normally you will end up with --- { a: [ { '0': 10, '1': 11 }, 84 ], b: 13, c: 70 }
--- but I am not sure this is intended or expected, maybe a deep merged is necessary

Comment: this object a: { 0: 10, 1: 11 }  must be a:[10,11]

Comment: the author says --- desired result : 
combinedObject = {a:{0:10,1:84}, b:13, c:70}

Comment: also, with the solution you provide, you end up with { a: [ { 0: 10, 1: 11 }, 84 ] }, please read my comment entirely

Comment: myObject.1 // fails, properties cannot begin with numbers

Comment: each keys are automatically and natively converted as a string with javascript which means you can access it through myObject['1'];

Comment: Just as example you can have an object with a key such as --- myObj = { 'Connection-string': 'value' } ---  and you can't access it through --- myObj.Connection-string --- you must in that case access it through --- myObj['Connection-string'] and it is the same wit myObj['1']

Comment: the 3rd one is your answer

Comment: It is not the point, I was just answering your comment about the access of myObj.1 which fails

Comment: Anyway ^^ all solutions are still valuable

Comment: Your edit still does not work in case a property is an object…

Comment: the question is simple and I answer the question. because it can be more changeable than this, what about `const obj1 = {a:10,b:13}
const obj2 = {a:{a:{a:[10,20],c:70},c:70},c:70}

Comment: A simple recursive method resolve that problem, this is why I mentioned  wrapping in a recursive in case its needed ^^ but agree with you, keep it simple

Comment: Thanks everyone for breaking it down. As some people have suggested, it has to be a:[10,11] , not a: { 0: 10, 1: 11 }. And that other answer has a method to do exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is two solutions,
The first one, merge the values of the keys into an object under the same key name.
The second one, propose a way to merge them as you mention, but it is a bit more complicated to maintain the index of each key but it is still possible.

The result of both options looks like that

```
// Option 1
{ a: [ 10, 11, 84 ], b: [ 13, 12 ], c: 70, d: 50 }

// Option 2
{
  a: { '0': 10, '1': 11, '2': 84 },
  b: { '0': 13, '1': 12 },
  c: 70,
  d: 50
}
```

And here is how it is achieved

```js
const obj1 = { a: { 0: 10, 1: 11 }, b: 13 }
const obj2 = { a: 84, b: 12, c: 70, d: 50 }
const allKeys = Object.keys({ ...obj1, ...obj2 });

const merged1 = {};
for (const key of allKeys) {
    const isObj1Object = typeof obj1[key] === 'object';
    const isObj2Object = typeof obj2[key] === 'object';
    if (obj1[key] && obj2[key]) {
        merged1[key] = [
            ...(isObj1Object ? Object.values(obj1[key]) : [obj1[key]]),
            ...(isObj2Object ? Object.values(obj2[key]) : [obj2[key]]),
        ];
    } else if (obj1[key] || obj2[key]) {
        merged1[key] = obj1[key] || obj2[key];
    }
}

console.log(merged1);

const merged2 = {};
for (const key of allKeys) {
    if (obj1[key] && obj2[key]) {
        const isObj1Object = typeof obj1[key] === 'object';
        const isObj2Object = typeof obj2[key] === 'object';
        merged2[key] = {
            ...(
                isObj1Object
                    ? Object.values(obj1[key]).reduce((acc, v, i) => {
                        acc[Object.keys(obj2[key]).length + i] = v;
                        return acc;
                    }, {})
                    : (
                        isObj2Object
                            ? { [Object.keys(obj2[key]).length]: obj1[key] }
                            : { 0: obj1[key] }
                    )
            ),
            ...(
                isObj2Object
                    ? Object.values(obj2[key]).reduce((acc, v, i) => {
                        acc[Object.keys(obj1[key]).length + i] = v;
                        return acc;
                    }, {})
                    : (
                        isObj1Object
                            ? { [Object.keys(obj1[key]).length]: obj2[key] }
                            : { 1: obj2[key] })
            ),
        };
    } else if (obj1[key] || obj2[key]) {
        merged2[key] = obj1[key] || obj2[key];
    }
}

console.log(merged2);
```

You can test the different options here [playground](https://jsfiddle.net/gu9xadmq/)

If you would like to have a deep merged without any level limitation you would have to update the code to use a recursive method.